# Why is my Image too far left-aligned in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, html, image

I have this code, which is behaving differently in firefox vs chrome.

```
<h2>Presenting 
<span style="font-weight:bold">Analytics by </span> 
<div class="fi_logo"><img src="IMAGEURL" /></div>
</h2>
```

the class fi_logo referenced above is :

```
.fi_logo {
    min-width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 40px;  
    position: absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left: 262px;
    float:right;
}
```

In firefox, there is an offset caused by margin-left in fi_logo between the image and the text(in h2). If i dont add the margin-left, then the image overlaps the text in chrome.

So, in short, if i add the margin-left property, it works in chrome, whereas it causes a large offset in firefox. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: you have a syntax error <img src="IMAGEURL"</div> the img is not closed

Comment: and in your css you need a '.' before fi_logo

Comment: you basically need the text"Presenting Analytics by" and then the image on the right. Is that right. Lemme know and i'll suggest you a better way of doing it thru CSS

Comment: give an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ . So easy to solve

Comment: i tried the same code not sure about the image size, result is same browsers firefox 4.0, chrome.

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle of the origional code: http://jsfiddle.net/mpL79/

Comment: a div inside <h2> ? using margin-left and left both ? there's your answer,  work on this, and it'll get fixed.

Comment: @bikerabhinav totally agree with you on the margin-left/left thing, but a div inside a h2 should be fine (if not semantically). It's no different than a div inside a div which is pretty common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/bikerabhinav/mpL79/2/ 
Use combination of position relative and absolute.
Also, do not use div inside h2 - bad markup

Comment: you can ( and need to ) accept one of the answers as best/most suited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you set .fi_logo display:block

Comment: Perhaps you are having difficulties because you are trying to float and position:absolute.  I'm not sure if this is invalid code per se, but I cannot see how it would ever make sense to do.

Comment: i appreciate your commments here.. i am a newbie to the world of css.. i am trying to do a hot-fix for already existing code there is which is written by someone else. I will try to get more info about this and let you know.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag inside the `div` is not closed properly, and in the `css` the class definition is wrong; the class is defined by a dot (`.`);

Comment: edited the question. it was a problem in posting the question, not the code.. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is with specific browser version. 
I checked it in FF 3.6.2, which return same result like Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like you still haven't sorted this out so I will make a little more commentary.

I cannot say exactly what is causing the browser inconsistencies without doing a bunch of trial and error, but I think that the way to fix it is to rethink the way you are positioning the image.

It seems awful convoluted to be positioning the img absolutely, floating it, and adding a left margin.  Given all of that it is unclear what precisely you are even trying to accomplish with this code.

If you edit your question to describe how you want the image positioned, I (or someone else) would be more than happy to recommend  a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid. You cannot have a div inside a heading. I also question the float and absolute positioning on the same element. I also wonder if you are using a doctype.